# How to get id value in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, codeigniter

I am using **angular js**

When i console **$scope.id** in `app.controller` i am getting this type of result:  ***Object { id="2"}***
and i am passing `$scope.id` in ajax and it is going to pass like *object{id=2}* but it should pass just **`2`**.

What i have tried is:

```
app.controller('AssingPackageController2', function ($scope, $compile, $state) {
        function getPackageListForAssing() {
            console.log($scope.id); // here
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + 'subscription/getPackage/' + $scope.id
                },
                error: function (e) {
                }
            });
        }
        getPackageListForAssing();
  });
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$scope.id.id` instead of `$scope.id` here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'subscription/getPackage/' + $scope.id.id
    },
    error: function (e) {
    }
});
```

`$scope.id` is an object here.